# How do I get an aggregate of all the stats from all uWSGI vassals using uwsgitop?

Tags: configuration, monitoring, performance-monitoring, uwsgi

### TL;DR

Can anyone tell me how I may get `uwsgitop` to monitor all of my vassals in my emperor-vassal setup in one shot?

---

I have an emperor-vassal setup for my uWSGI server, and I need to monitor all my vassals. I could always check my application logs for the various data, but it is more convenient to have a real-time updating, comprehensive display of all statistics.

So, I tried a couple of things:

1. I created a common .ini file which contains the following:

   ```
   [uwsgi]
   stats = stats_vassal.sock
   ```

   Then, in each vassal's .ini file I include that common .ini file. The problem with this approach is that I don't get any meaningful data when I run [`uwsgitop`](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgitop) with the `stats_vassal.sock` file. My hypothesis as to why this is happening is that the data in that socket keeps getting overwritten by stats from some vassal that isn't in use.

   So then I switched to....
2. In each vassal's .ini file, I set an option `stats = stats_%n.sock`. Now, I can run `uwsgitop` on each `stats_*.sock` file to monitor that specific vassal.

   But I want to be able to monitor all vassals in one go. `uwsgitop` seems to accept only one argument.

I've looked into uWSGI's [Metrics subsystem](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Metrics.html), and the ["file" stats pusher](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Metrics.html#file) seems to be what I want since it keeps appending to one file. However, when I tried to put `stats-push = file:path=stats_%n.sock,freq=1` in each of my vassal .ini files **OR** when I tried to put `stats-push = file:path=stats_vassal.sock,freq=1` in my common vassal .ini file, I get the following error when I restart uWSGI:

> unable to find "file" stats_pusher

I then tried to include the `stats_pusher_file` plugin in the same .ini file, but got the following error:

> !!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: ./stats_pusher_file_plugin.so: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory !!!

And this is where I hit a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately uwsgitop didn't have such possibilities, but i wrote "patch" and with my changes there is ability to use uwsgitop this way : `uwsgitop /var/stats` and it shows all vassal workers information separately on one screen.

You can check code [here](https://github.com/generikjano/uwsgitop/blob/a053e287b1d19fd0baddd1447c28883025ff13fa/uwsgitop)

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4DpW.jpg)